# Automatic transposing Excel user data in a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have some big Excel files like this (note: other variables are omitted for brevity):

[image]

and would need to build a corresponding Pandas DataFrame with the following structure.

[image]

I am trying to develop a Pandas code for, at least, parsing the first column and transposing the id and the full of each user. Could you help with this?

Comment: You probably need to write a small parser. NB.I believe your output is incorrect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way that I would tackle it, and I am assuming there are likely to be more efficient ways, is to import the excel file into a dataframe, and then iterate through it to grab the details you need for each line. Store that information in a dictionary, and append each formed line into a list. This list of dictionaries can then be used to create the final dataframe.

Please note, I made the following assumptions:

- Your excel file is named 'data.xlsx' and in the current working directory
- The index next to each person increments by one EVERY time
- All people have a position described in brackets next to the name
- I made up the column names, as none were provided

```py
import pandas as pd

# import the excel file into a dataframe (df)
filename = 'data.xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel(filename, names=['col1', 'col2'])

# remove blank rows
df.dropna(inplace=True)

# reset the index of df
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

# initialise the variables
counter = 1
name_pos = ''
name = ''
pos = ''
line_dict = {}
list_of_lines = []

# iterate through the dataframe
for i in range(len(df)):
    if df['col1'][i] == counter:
        name_pos = df['col2'][i].split(' (')
        name = name_pos[0]
        pos = name_pos[1].rstrip(name_pos[1][-1])
        p_index = counter
        counter += 1
    else:
        date = df['col1'][i].strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
        amount = df['col2'][i]
        line_dict = {'p_index': p_index, 'name': name, 'position': pos, 'date':date, 'amount': amount}
        list_of_lines.append(line_dict)

final_df = pd.DataFrame(list_of_lines)
```

**OUTPUT:**
[image]